# Reverse Engineering a Google Form into a Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

It is currently possible to create a Google Form from a script as seen here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/

Is it possible to re-produce a form's source code given that it was created normally in the forms editor?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "source code."  If you mean getting all the information out of one Form, and reproducing the exact same content in another Form, then 'Yes' that can be done in code.  But, the ID numbers of the questions would be different in the copy if it's all done in code.  But if you want an exact copy, you can just copy the file.

Comment: For source code I mean having a script which can be run to create the form from scratch (which can be edited otherwise a simple copy and paste would suffice) from what I've gathered this is only possible if your use Google scripts to create the form in the first place. I was just wondering wether it would be possible the other way round.

Comment: You can edit a Form with code that was first created "manually."  If that's what you mean.  It doesn't matter how the Form was created in the first place or how many times it was changed.  You could change the same Form a million times if you wanted to.